# Typescript: What is the difference between an optional and a not optional class member with default value

Tags: typescript

```
class Stuff {
  id: number[] = [];
  age?: number[] = [];
}

let p = new Stuff();
p.id.push(1);
p.age.push(1);
alert(p.id);
alert(p.age);
```

They both seem to be defined and able to receive the new value. So my question(s) is(are): What is the difference between the two parameters? Are there relevant initialization situations where the second member may be undefined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that the attribute types are different in terms of optional assignments later on. Hover over those attributes:

```
(property) Stuff.id: number[]
(property) Stuff.age?: number[] | undefined
```

In the case of `id`, your assignment is obligatory, because the initialization of a non optional class attribute has to happen in the constructor or as direct assignment.
Although both members are not undefined per default, TypeScript will allow you to assign `undefined` only for `age` later on.

```
// you cannot do that...
p.id = undefined
// , but this is allowed
p.age = undefined
```

Also if you have `strictNullChecks` enabled in the compiler options, your sample already provokes an error. As `age` *can* contain undefined, TypeScript is not sure of this. You would need to check it first:

```
// Object is possibly 'undefined'.
p.age.push(1);

// works
if (p.age === undefined) p.age = [];
else p.age.push(1);
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAEDKAuBXAZs6BvAUNaBLAJgFzQB2iAtgEYCmATgNoC60AvNEwNzbRgDm1AfmJkqdJq3aMuAX0yYQ1eNAAOEktQDucJKgAUASi7KAdAWPLEEABa6AjIcy40uk32qsWbRCXzVkudXx9FWM3CU5MahAId1d+c0sbey4wBVp4F1MglLSMuOoHTAB6IugATwB7RGhgMBISCqV8Cuh4KzB4Yy7MEwIJb19-QK4S6AAaaEpEJTbcGDmeEBAKjWp8HtD+fp8-ALWuIA)

Hope, that helps.